# Tensor products of weakly compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces. Denote by $X\otimes_\varepsilon Y$ the injective tensor product of $X$ and $Y$. Also, let $A\subset X, B\subset Y$ be any sets. Set $A\otimes B = \{a\otimes b\colon a\in A, b\in B\}$. Can we deduce that if $A$ and $B$ are weakly compact then so is $A\otimes B$ just because the bilinear map $(a,b)\mapsto a\otimes b$, $X\times Y\to X\otimes_\varepsilon Y$ is continuous?

Comment: It is enough to show that $\theta:X\times Y\to X\otimes_\varepsilon Y: (x,y)\to x\otimes_\varepsilon y$ is contnuous when $X$, $Y$ and $X\otimes_\varepsilon Y$ are considered with weak topologies, i.e. to show $$\forall\varphi\in (X\otimes_\varepsilon Y)^*\quad \exists C>0\quad\exists(f_i)_{i=1,n}\subset X^*\quad\exists\quad(g_k)_{k=1,m}\subset Y^*\quad\forall x\in X\quad\forall y\in Y\quad|\varphi(\theta(x,y))|\leq C\max\limits_{i=1,n}|f_i(x)|\max\limits_{k=1,n}|g_k(y)|$$ Now it is worth to recall that functional on injective tensor product have explicit description

Comment: Preciesly, $$\forall \varphi\in (X\otimes_\varepsilon Y)^*\quad\exists \mu\in M((\operatorname{Ball}_{X^*},w^*)\times (\operatorname{Ball}_{Y^*},w^*))\quad\forall x\in X\quad\forall y\in Y\quad \varphi(x\otimes_\varepsilon y)=\int_{\operatorname{Ball}_{X^*}\times \operatorname{Ball}_{Y^*}} f(x) g(y) d\mu(f,g)$$ May be this could help you.